# Kubuntu 21.10 stopped connecting to internet via wifi

Tags: networking, wireless, kubuntu, 21.10

**Problem:** no Internet connection after connecting to home wifi "Limited Connectivity"

**Machine details:** Dell Precision 3560 / Kubuntu 21.10 (upgraded from 21.04)

**Logs:**

```bsh
$ ping 8.8.8.8
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
$ sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[   28.768547] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   28.777747] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[   28.777761] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
[   28.777980] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 63.c04f3485.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-63.ucode op_mode iwlnvm
[   28.872420] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz, REV=0x354
[   29.060415] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: ec:63:d7:d2:b8:83
[   29.078756] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: wlp0s20f3: renamed from wlan0
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
0000:00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 [8086:a0f0] (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 [8086:4070]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

*Side note:* My other laptop, Thinkpad T550/Kubuntu 21.10 has no problems with Internet from the same wifi network.

---

solution: [Kubuntu 21.10 stopped connecting to internet via wifi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1409196/kubuntu-21-10-stopped-connecting-to-internet-via-wifi/1409225#1409225)

Comment: This is a question & answer site. Please add the solution as an answer. Don't add SOLVED to the title.

Comment: Indeed, edited.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**

I noticed when I connect to hotspot from my mobile phone, the Internet is working. Thus, I did:

```
$ sudo su-
# cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
# rm FAULTY_CONNECTION_NAME
# exit
$ nmcli con delete FAULTY_CONNECTION_NAME
```

and reestablished connection from scratch.